# Fetch a last occurrence of row containing a substring

Tags: tcl

I have a string a which is

```
set $a "I have a blah blah
xyz who r u
I have a car
xyz j r u"

I have a blah blah 
xyz who r u   // Line 2 which contains substring xyz
I have a car
xyz j r u     //Line 4 which contains substring xyz
```

I am using foreach loop on variable a after splitting the string variable $a by new line.

```
set substring "xyz"
set b [split $a '\n']
foreach eachLine $b {
            if{[string first $substring $eachLine] != -1} {
                puts "$eachLine"   
            }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
xyz j r u  //Line 4 which contains substring xyz
```

Currently,this would print both line 2 and line 4.

In the above code, i am trying to fetch the last line which has occurance of substring "xyz".
Can you please suggest any good way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store `$eachLine` in a variable and then only print it after the loop ends.

```
set lastSeen ""
foreach eachLine $b {
    if {[string first $substring $eachLine] != -1} {
        set lastSeen $eachLine
    }
}
puts $lastSeen
```

You could reverse the list and print the *first* time you see it:

```sh
foreach line [lreverse $b] {
    if {[string first $substring $line] != -1} {
        puts $line
        break   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in way to search a list is the `lsearch` command. You can extract only the last occurrence using the `lindex` command:

```
puts [lindex [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $b (?q)$substring] end]
```

This uses the `-regexp` option so the search pattern is not anchored (i.e.: It may occur anywhere within the list element). Then the `(?q)` embedded option suppresses interpreting any character in $substring as regular expression syntax, resulting in a search on the literal text stored in $substring.

Answer (score 0):

Walk the list of lines from its end forward, and stop on the first match:

```
set i [expr {[llength $b] - 1}]

while {$i >= 0} {
  set eachLine [lindex $b $i]
  if {[string first $substring $eachLine] != -1} {
    puts "$eachLine"
    break;
  }
  incr i -1
}
```

This way you do not double the list (`lreverse`) or process the whole list (`lsearch`), only to retrieve one match, if any at all.